# Proportion of strings with ascending letters

Tags: code-golf, string, math

### Challenge

- Construct `n` strings, each with three distinct letters, chosen randomly with equal probability.
- Print the proportion `k/n` where `k` is the number of strings such that all three characters are in ascending order. Print also those `k` strings.

### Input

- The only input is `n` (and thus it must be a positive integer).

### Outputs

- The proportion `k/n` must be truncated to two decimal places.
- The strings that are in ascending order of letters.

### Requirements

- The letters must come from the English alphabet.
- You cannot print the value of `k`.

### Examples

- Input: `6`, Output: `0.16 agh`
- Input: `1`, Output: `1.00 suv`
- Input: `9`, Output: `0.22 hls jqr`

### How to Win

- Fewest number of bytes wins.

Comment: Just curious: Why do you keep changing the examples? They are examples, not test cases! The output will obviously vary from run to run for any such program.

The probability of making a word with 3 distinct letters which are in ascending order is exactly `1/6`, and given `n`, the number `k` is a random variable that is binomially distributed with parameters `(n, 1/6)`. The expected value for `k` is exactly `n/6`, and so the quotient `k/n` is just approximating 1/6.

Comment: The problem remains that the generation of the strings is an unobservable requirement. Since there are only 6 possible orderings of three distinct characters, and only one of those is in strict ascending order, the same result would be obtained by throwing a die n times and showing the proportion of 6’s.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire that makes them unobservable. For example, I think https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP0@jQjMtJz@/SMPQwECrKCkzLz9Xw1CnQsdQ30xTv0JTHyj8P03DTPM/AA would give the correct answers but doesn’t generate any strings.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire it’s still an unobservable requirement since you’re relying on reading the code. Specifying precise means of doing something tends not to be looked on well here: other than the standard loopholes, it is generally better to indicate (using our I/O defaults) your inputs and outputs and leave the implementation up to the answerer. One option here would be to specify an output that includes the n strings and the proportion that are in ascending order, while leaving the precise characters and the output mechanism (STDOUT, list, array, object, etc. ) to the implementation.

Comment: See https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10002/42248

Comment: @NickKennedy Is this compromise okay?

Comment: Outputing both a list of ascending word, and the quotient `k/n` seems a bit overkill. Maybe it makes sense to only output the ascending words? The quotient `k/n` can easily be computed from the list of ascending words. But perhaps one shouldn't change the challenge once its posted..

Comment: What is the point of "must be truncated to two decimal places?

Comment: Does the string have to be three characters long? Or is it okay if it is more than three characters, but has three distinct characters?

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance Exactly three distinct characters.

Comment: What happens if our language of choice can't round decimals?

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 31 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

13 bytes to cater for the truncation requirement!

```
ØaẊ⁸Ð¡Ḋḣ€3ṢƑƇðL÷+⁵×ȷ2ḞṾs2j”.Ḋṭ⁸
```

A monadic link which, given an integer, yields a list.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AVEArv9qZWxsef//w5hh4bqK4oG4w5DCoeG4iuG4o@KCrDPhuaLGkcaHw7BMw7cr4oG1w5fItzLhuJ7hub5zMmrigJ0u4biK4bmt4oG4/8OHS///MTY)** (footer joins the list with spaces)

---

If (1) we remove the truncation requirement and (2) "The letters must come from the English alphabet" implies that we may choose any subset of three or more such letters then this 16 works:

```
“ḃ»Ẋ⁸Ð¡⁼ƇḢ$ðL÷;⁸
```

[Try this one](https://tio.run/##ATQAy/9qZWxsef//4oCc4biDwrvhuorigbjDkMKh4oG8xofhuKIkw7BMw7c74oG4/8OHS///MTAw) (only uses A, B, and C)

---

If we may also avoid the unobservable creation of all the strings as part of of our code. then this 15 works:

```
6ẋX€ỊƇ“ḃ»ẋðL÷;⁸
```

[Try this one](https://tio.run/##ATEAzv9qZWxsef//NuG6i1jigqzhu4rGh@KAnOG4g8K74bqLw7BMw7c74oG4/8OHS///MTAw) (only uses A, B, and C, and does not create any unordered strings)

Comment: Although it seems an unnecessary requirement, the current spec calls for truncation at 2 decimal places.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that, what an odd requirement. Updated.

Comment: sorry to be a pain, but the official spec is to truncate rather than round. I don’t think Jelly has a built in, so (unless I’m missing something) it’s either convert to string and head, or it’s multiply by 100, floor, divide by 100.

Comment: LOL what a mess

Comment: Neither of those suggestions work if `1` must prodce `1.00` either.

Comment: Fixed by adding ten, multiplying by 100, un-evaluating, splitting into chunks of length two, joining with a `'.'`, and dequeuing (whew).

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 25 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
;ÆBö3Ãf_¶ñ
u»UÊ/N)h2)ú0,4
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=O8ZC9jPDZl%2b28Qp1u1XKL04paDIp%2bjAsNA&input=Ng)

Comment: [20](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=O8ZC9jPDZl%2b28Qp1KFXKL04gaDI&input=Ng)?

Comment: @Shaggy I never knew that you could divide an array like that, and I forgot about `N`. Nice!

Comment: Hooray for JS's implicit casting!

Comment: Wait, `N.h()` won't work here due to the stupid & unnecessary requirement that the result be *truncated* to 2 decimal places.

Comment: @Shaggy Fixed. It's really convenient that `N.h()` returns a string

Comment: It doesnt look like it fits the requirement that all three letters be distinct, unless Im missing something

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 131 bytes

It seems like having to print the string complicates the program...

```python
from random import*
n=int(input())
o=[]
a=['a','b','c']
x=0
for i in range(n):
 o+=[sample(a,3)]
 x+=a==o[-1]
print('%.2f'%(x/n),o)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYxBDsIgEADv@wouDWBRq40Xk30J4YBalER2CWKCr8f2MJnTTP7VF9PceyicRPH0WBVT5lJ3QBipqkj5W5XWwGgdeLTSSyNvK3fpoOEEgYuIItLWPxdF@gqCR7Qfn/J7Ud7M2oFoI3pEtvuTg1y2sxwO5yAH1Y6kDeveL9Mf)

Comment: [90 bytes](https://tio.run/##FchBDoIwEADAu6/ohbBLGoQSLyT9AT9QD2ug2oTdNks9@Pqqp0kmf8oriauLv9Wd@LGSEUv@Olpnp/vcNr0LbQNjP3THm4G8P4jzvgHZCUNSE00UoyTPDQTxLHgKmvg/64/IOWnpatYoxSxwGbB@AQ) BD

Comment: Please see the (hopefully final) edit.

Comment: Along with fixing to fit the new spec with respect to printing the strings it also needs to truncate rather than round (`1`->`1.00`, `0.166667`->`0.16`, `0`->`0.00`).

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 26 bytes

```
FNQKO.PG3IqKSK=ZhZK;.RcZQ2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/380v0NtfL8Dd2LPQO9jbNiojyttaLyg5KtDo/38LAA)

Does what OP wants, +4 bytes due to truncation requirement.

### How it works

```
FNQKO.PG3IqKSK=ZhZK;.RcZQ2
FNQ                        - For N in Input
   K                       - K is equal to
    O.P 3                  - A random permutation length 3 of...
       G                   - The lowercase alphabet
         IqKSK             - If K is sorted
              =ZhZ         - Increment Z (which is autoinitialized to 0)
                  K        - Implicitly print K
                   ;  cZQ  - End loop, float division of Z by the input
                    .R   2 - Round to 2 decimal points
```

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 24 bytes

```
FNQI!O6=ZhZSO.PG3;.RcZQ2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/380v0FPR38w2KiMq2F8vwN3YWi8oOSrQ6P9/CwA)

Cheat answer but since it only saves two bytes im not gonna bother. Also +4 due to truncation

Comment: How does the second one cheat? The two seem to behave the same

Comment: It doesnt generate strings and check if theyre sorted; it only generates sorted strings with a 1/6 chance (which is the probability that a random string of length 3 will be sorted)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 44 bytes

```
((4j2":%~),@,~[:u:97+26/:~@?~]#3:)1#.0=?@$&6
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/pvqWhlGGumaGWprs6lpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/NTRMsoyUrFTrNHUcdOqirUqtLM21jcz0reoc7OtilY2tNA2V9Qxs7R1U1Mz@a3JxFaUWlmYWpSqo55XmphZlJqtzFSXmpeTnZlalAu3hSk3OyFdIUzA0wMcyMkOwFBDM/wA)

Note: This one does not actually construct the strings (the one below does) but its output has an identical probability distribution.  I agree with Nick Kennedy on this point.

---

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 48 bytes

```
(];~4j2":(%~#))[:<@u:"1[:(97+(-:/:~)"1#])26?~#&3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/pvqWhlGGumaGWprs6lpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/NWKt60yyjJSsNFTrlDU1o61sHEqtlAyjrTQszbU1dK30reo0lQyVYzWNzOzrlNWM/2tycRWlFpZmFqUqqOeV5qYWZSarcxUl5qXk52ZWpQLt4kpNzshXSFMwNMDHMjJDsBQQzP8A)

Note: Because the required output does not have a homogeneous data type, J requires us to box it.

Comment: Strings in your first submission dont seem to be in ascending order

Comment: @frank ty.  fixed now.